# jquery dropzone remove button is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I created a drag and drop interface for image upload using dropzone plugin.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>acc/assets/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>

<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>acc/assets/dropzone/upload.php" 
      class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
</form>
```

I also wrote the php code for uploading images and it is working.

The problem is there is no remove buttons for removing an image from the drop area. How can I enable that button?

Answer (score 7):

you can read how to configure it here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_6

for create options to a dropzone that you create by simply using the dropzone class, you need to create an object called after your form's id.

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
//options here
}
```

To add a remove or cancel button, you have to pass the option  `addRemoveLinks`

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>acc/assets/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>

Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        addRemoveLinks: true

}

<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>acc/assets/dropzone/upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

You can also take a look at this options:

- **dictCancelUpload**: If addRemoveLinks is true, the text to be used for the cancel upload link.
- **dictCancelUploadConfirmation**: If addRemoveLinks is true, the text to be used for confirmation when cancelling upload.
- **dictRemoveFile**: If addRemoveLinks is true, the text to be used to remove a file

Comment: Seems to be buggy for me? It showed up yesterday, today it doesn't anymore.. Did this change in the 2017 version?